# Structure a webapp using RequireJS

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, require.js

I've written a small webapp in JavaScript, and am now essentially rewriting it to use RequireJS.  I'm doing this partly to get more familiar with RequireJS (which I have little experience with), as well as for ease of maintaining and upgrading the app.

I'm hoping to get feedback on whether the structure I'm looking at implementing is reasonable/useful/extensible/totally insane.  I've been through the require docs, reading related SO posts and some samples on GitHub, but I'm not sure I'm totally 'getting' Require.

If there are fundamental flaws in the logic it'd be great to get some links to resources (either JS or RequireJS specific), and to get feedback about the overall structure of the app itself.  Suggestions for design patterns also very much appreciated, there's some stuff in there that feels kind of counter intuitive.

**main.js**

```
require({

    paths: {
        jquery: '../bower_components/jquery/jquery'
    }

}, function() {
    'use strict';
    require(['jquery', 'app', 'reader', 'env'], function($, App, Reader, Env) {

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var app = new App(
                new Reader(),
                new Env()
            );

        });

    })

});
```

**app.js**

```
define(function() {

    return function(reader, env) {

        this.reader = reader,
        this.env = env

    };

});
```

**reader.js** (it's an online e-reader)

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    return function() {

        this.components = [],
        this.firstPage = null,
        this.lastPage = null,
        this.maxFontSize = function() {
            return this.env.isIOS() ? 120 : 160;
        }

    };

});
```

**env.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {

    return function() {

        this.isIOS = function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i) ? true : false; // for example.  
        }

    };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is honestly pretty good. I usually use `requirejs.config` to set the paths and configurations on require (it's going to grow a lot as you add things like shims, urlArgs, etc). You will also probably want to reuse it in several places. [See my blog article on how I recommend doing this.](https://github.com/togakangaroo/Blog/blob/master/setting-up-requirejs.md) The general idea is that you don't use `data-main` to bootstrap things, you instead have a request for the configuration file and another to actually bootstrap the specific page of your application.

Next, I'll ask why bother injecting `reader` and `env` manually into `application`? Injecting dependencies is what RequireJs already does.

**app.js**

```
define(['reader', 'env'], function(Reader, Env) {
    return function() {
        this.reader = new Reader(),
        this.env = new Env()
    };
});
```

Finally, a couple notes on your specific files - you probably want to name those top-level functions even when returning immediately

**env.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    return function Env() {
      ...
    };
});
```

That both makes it clear from within what module you're in, the fact that you expect it to be used with `new`, and will generate nicer stacktraces.

I'll also point out that - it's a matter of style but you're on CR so I consider it solicited - hardly ever is code made more bugproof or more legible by using constructor functions.  **reader.js** could just as easily be the following and not depend on someone remembering to use `new` and always bind functions.

```
var env = {
    components: [],
    firstPage: null,
    lastPage: null,
    maxFontSize: function() {
                   return this.env.isIOS() ? 120 : 160;
                 }
};
return env;
```

Comment: hey thanks very much! injecting the deps manually was part of what was feeling strange about what i had going on in the Q. i set up the `require.config`, named the top level fns (the `console.log` looks _logical_ now) and removed constructors (`reader.js`) where superfluous. thanks also for the link!